# how to add custom contact field in android contacts

Tags: android

i want to add a custom contact label  like (home,mobile,work,MY_LABEL) while adding a contact from my application  and fetch the number from my custom label as well.

OR if it is not possible can i add a new field like (phone,email) with my custom field.

Please someone has any idea how to do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible to add custom contact label. For this, you have to create a SyncAdapter & Authenticator and then create a Account. Declare the new custom field you need to add as meta value for SyncAdapter in Manifest file

Look into SampleSyncAdapter code in google project for an example. Also, I found this link as very useful reference- http://www.c99.org/2010/01/23/writing-an-android-sync-provider-part-2/

Comment: Thanks Sukumar i'll check this link.